# Sending email notification to users when their post is published in WordPress. Why Multiple times?

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress site where users can post from the front-end and the post status goes as Draft.

Now when I publish the post from Admin panel, the notification email is sent more than one time. I need to send email once.

Below my code:

```
if (is_admin()) {
    function notifyauthor($post_id) { 
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $subject = "Post publish notification";
        $headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).' <my_email@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        $message = "
            Hi ".$author->display_name.",
            
            Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
            
            View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
            
            Thank You, Admin"
            ;
            
        wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
        add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
}
```

I tried `current_user_can('administrator')` insteed to `is_admin()`, but same result I got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many hooks will actually run more than one time.  The simple solution is to add a counter by way of post_meta after the first iteration, then check it doesn't exist.  This isn't tested, but should work.

```
function notifyauthor($post_id) {
    if (is_admin() && !(metadata_exists('post', $post_id, 'sent_notification_email'))) {
        $post = get_post($post_id);
        $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
        $subject = "Post publish notification";
        $headers = 'From: '.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).' <my_email@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
        $message = "
            Hi ".$author->display_name.",
            
            Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.
            
            View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."
            
            Thank You, Admin";

        wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
        // Set a meta key as a counter
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sent_notification_email', '1');
    }
}
add_action('publish_post', 'notifyauthor');
```

Comment: Seems it worked. Testing more... Thank you.